# SgmlLinkExtractor regex for the next 20 pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl through the first 20 pages with scrapy using SgmlLinkExtractor. What would be the regex for the next 20 pages when:

start_url is `url.com/montlab?cPath=17` while next page address is `url.com/montlab?cPath=17&page_num=2` and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'page_num=(1[0-9]|[1-9])',)
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't pulls the other pages.

this is how I have it:

`rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'page_num=([0-9]|[1-9])')), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)`

Comment: Which other pages? The above regex specifically pulls only the 20 urls that you mentioned in your question. Also, the regex in the code you pasted and my answer are different. You are missing a `1` at the beginning of the regex.